# Can Evolution warn me when emailing a colleague from my personal account?

Tags: email, evolution

I use Evolution to manage both my work and personal account. Sometimes I accidentally send work emails from my personal account. Is it possible to set up a rule to warn or block this?

Something like: *<if sending from "personal@example.com" and recipients include "*@work.com" then ask "are you sure?">*

Comment: I would love to have such a feature too!